# MYSQL GROUP BY RECORD

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am beginner and I am stuck over a problem, I have a table in which I have a large data about restaurants, I have some restaurants that have multiple branches, so I want to display them like below as you can see I have three entries in my table for restaurant C, and i want to display them under a single name.

```
Restaurant A:
  123 B town
Restaurant B:
  123 C town
Restaurant C:
  1 A Town
  2 B Town 
  3 C Town
```

Problem:
I have made a query, but it only displays a single entry for each restaurant even if there are multiple records against the restaurant.

```
SELECT * FROM Restaurants
GROUP BY NAME
```

Comment: The function of GROUP BY is to return a single record fro all matching values. So it will only return one record for each restaurant name if that is what you have grouped by. Sounds like all you need to do is ORDER BY

Comment: ORDER BY just simply order my sql record but it show what i want it.

Comment: If you only want to print the name once, then only print it when it changes, but without you showing how you are displaying your results, I can't show you how to change it to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample Data

```
resturant       |   branch
-----------------------------
Restaurant A    |   123 B town
Restaurant B    |   123 C town
Restaurant C    |   1 A Town
Restaurant C    |   2 B Town 
Restaurant C    |   3 C Town
```

Query

```
SELECT 
    resturant,
    GROUP_CONCAT(branch)
FROM Restaurants
GROUP BY NAME
```

Result

```
resturant       |   branch
-----------------------------
Restaurant A    |   123 B town
Restaurant B    |   123 C town
Restaurant C    |   1 A Town,2 B Town,3 C Town
```

Use php [explode()](http://pk1.php.net/explode) on branch

Answer (score 1):

You would not want to group them by name, as that grouping will show only one row per group.
fetch all the rows, and then do the grouping in PHP using an associative array.

Or use `GROUP_CONCAT` , that would give you a comma seperated list of towns in a column.

eg.

`SELECT ame,some_id,GROUP_CONCAT(branch_town) from my_table GROUP BY NAME`

Answer (score 1):

I would:

```
SELECT * FROM Restaurants
ORDER BY NAME
```

And in your php script - please remind that I'm not aware of your table naming, so this is more or less pseudocode.

```
$prevGroup = false;
// How ever you normally iterate through your rows
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $group = $row['name'];
    if($prevGroup != $group) {
        echo $row['name'];
        $prevGroup = $group;
    }
    echo $row['city'];
}
```